# Adding thumbnails of a Youtube channel's videos to a website in max resolution

Tags: reactjs, youtube, thumbnails

Is there a way to add all of the thumbnails of a Youtube channel's videos to a website in max resolution.

In my case, I'm working on a website using React. My current code displays the thumbnails in a carousel style. The issue I'm having is for youtube videos that aren't available in max resolution, the image of the thumbnail is completely grey and not what I expect (in picture below). My plan is to use a try and except to catch any case where the high res image is not generated. And if the high res image is unavailable, use the low res image instead (which I already figured out). Below is a screenshot of my current progress of my plan. The console.log in the catch is not getting triggered. I'm not sure why this is?

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72Vc.png)
[Image shown when high resolution thumbnail is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyrDc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.